# Function not allowing 2nd argument

Tags: python-3.x, arguments

I made a logging function , which takes 2 arguments: `log_message` and `mode`. For some reason, when I use the function and pass arguments, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/git/rip/rip.py", line 248, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/git/rip/rip.py", line 195, in main
    log('STARTING RIPPER', 'i')
TypeError: log() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Which is strange, since `log()` definitely takes 2 arguments.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import mmap
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from clint.textui import puts, colored

def log(log_message, mode='s'):
    log_date = '[' + time.strftime("%d.%m_%H:%M:%S") + ']'
    if mode == 'e':
        log_file = 'test_error.log'
        log_ouput = colored.white(log_date) + colored.red('[ERROR]' + log_message)
    elif mode == 'i':
        log_file = 'test_info.log'
        log_ouput = colored.white(log_date) + colored.yellow('[INFO]' + log_message)
    elif mode == 'c':
        log_file = 'test_info.log'
        log_ouput = colored.white(log_date) + colored.white('[COMMENT]' + log_message)
    else:
        log_file = 'test_download.log'
        log_ouput = colored.white(log_date) + colored.green(log_message)
    with open(log_file, 'a') as file_writer:
        file_writer.write(log_message + '\n')
    file_writer.close()
    puts(log_ouput)

def main():
    log('STARTING RIPPER', 'i')
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What is wrong with the example?

Comment: The above code looks OK. No issues with arguements. Please let us know how you run it.

Comment: For one thing, we can't run it to replicate the problem, it's neither *verifiable* nor *complete*. Please follow the link and read it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The code IS complete. I have added the imports.
I run it directly from the CLI: `python3 rip.py`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your interpreter (and don't know why) thinks that `'i'` is also a positonal argument (argument function with no name).

Try writing instead

```
log('STARTING RIPPER', mode='i')
```

And given that, btw, explicit is better than implicit, you should even write

```
log(log_message='STARTING RIPPER', mode='i')
```

Comment: This also doesn't work. Using your code exactly, I get the following error:`TypeError: log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'`

Comment: @ou_snaaksie. It looks like a name conflict. Try change the name of your `log` function, e.g. for `lOg` ?

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example works for me:

```
def log(log_message, mode='s'):
    print(log_message, mode)

log('STARTING RIPPER', 'i')
```

I think the `log` you are calling is a different `log`. Try

```
print(log.__module__)
```

to find out where the function comes from.

**Edit:**

To make sure that the signature of your function is what you expect, you can use

```
import inspect
print(inspect.signature(log))
```

which should return

```
(log_message, mode='s')
```

Comment: Returns `__main__`